# Go Google Cloud Vision API. Likelihood_POSSIBLE not declared by package vision

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I am using cloud vision api for the Go language.
I want to use `DetectSafeSearch`.
It returns `*vision.SafeSearchAnnotation`.

So, I wrote a code below.

```
if prop.Adult == vision.Likelihood_POSSIBLE { ... }
```

But I got a compile error `Likelihood_POSSIBLE not declared by package vision`.
But it seems `Likelihood_POSSIBLE` is exported in `vision` package.

Why did I got this error ?

And what is the proper way to handle `prop.Adult` ?

Comment: Can you post your import statements?

Comment: vision "cloud.google.com/go/vision/apiv1" , and "os"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

import visionpb "google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/cloud/vision/v1"